# MaskedTextBox доклеивать ведующие нули

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так, чтобы к числу в MaskedTextBox доклеивались ведущие нули слева?
Т.е мне надо чтобы число 123 выглядело как 000123
Если поставить Mask=999999, PromtChar = 0 то 123 выводится как 123000, т.е нули после числа а не перед

Answer (score 1):

По-моему элемент используется не по назначению.

> Использует маску, чтобы отличить допустимые данные, вводимые пользователем, от недопустимых.

Маска используется для валидации ввода значений. Для форматированного вывода используйте

```
string.Format("{0:D5}", 123); // 00123
```